# How to reorder map by nested values

Tags: sorting, flutter, dictionary, dart

What is the best way of sorting a map by its nested values in Dart?

```dart
Map myMap = {
  'A':{'foo':'#', 'pos':2},
  'B':{'baa':'#', 'pos':0},
  'C':{'yay':'#', 'pos':1},
}
Map mySortedMap = myMap.sort() ???
print(mySortedMap)

Output:
{
  'B':{'baa':'#', 'pos':0},
  'C':{'yay':'#', 'pos':1},
  'A':{'foo':'#', 'pos':2},
}
```

Comment: The `Map` interface is order agnostic. Some implementers (`LinkedHashMap`, `SplayTreeMap`) have defined orderings, but others don't (`HashMap`)

Comment: Ok. I don't need to keep the map in the order though, I just need to loop through the map in a certain order. Is there a way of looping through a map in a certain order without sorting it?

Comment: Turn it into an array of key/value pairs, sort by the values, then iterate that. But the fact have "pos" in your values suggests  that you probably shouldn't use map, in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite simple way: sort keys and create new map from those keys:

```dart
Map sortMapByPos(Map map) {
  final sortedKeys = map.keys.toList(growable: false)
    ..sort((k1, k2) => ((map[k1]['pos'] - map[k2]['pos'])));

  return Map.fromIterable(sortedKeys, key: (k) => k, value: (k) => map[k]);
}
```

Usage as below:

```dart
print(sortMapByPos(myMap));
```